# Summing up double series under constraints on the indexes

Tags: sum

I have the following double sum:
$$
\sum_{t=0}^\infty \sum_{\ell=0}^r \psi(t,\ell,r),
$$
only for even values of $t+\ell$ or $t+\ell=0$.

First, I thought, since $\ell$ depends on $r$, and $r$ can assume either even or odd values, then we should split the series in two, one for $r=2m$ and another for $r=2m+1$ ($m=0,1,2,...$). Also, $t+\ell$ is even if $t=2t_1$ and $\ell=2\ell_1$, or,  if $t=2t_1+1$ and $\ell=2\ell_1+1$. I am a bit confused how to adjust the new indexes. Also, another way to sum it up would be welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what your goal actually is. Do you just want to write the sum in a mathematically correct way so that it sums only over situations where $t + \ell$ is even? (By the way, 0 is even, you don't need it as a special case.) Or are you looking for a way to manipulate it, or program it somehow?

Comment: Hi, The computational package will sum only over the integers, so I just want to change the $t$ and $\ell$ terms inside the expression to allow the package to evaluate the sum under the constraint of $t+\ell$ being even.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches.

One is to zero out the extraneous terms:

$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty\ \sum_{\ell=0;\ t+l\text{ odd}}^r \psi(t,\ell,r) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty \sum_{\ell=0}^r \mathcal{I}(t+l\text{ even})\psi(t,\ell,r)$$

where the value of $\mathcal I$ is zero when its argument is false and one when its argument is true.

If you don't like the idea of summing lots of zeros, rewrite $\ell$ as  $2\lambda$ or $2\lambda+1$ depending on the parity of $t:$

$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty\ \sum_{\ell=0;\ t+l\text{ even}}^r \psi(t,\ell,r) =\sum_{t=0}^\infty \left\{\eqalign{&\sum_{\lambda=0}^{r/2}\psi(t, 2\lambda, r),& t\text{ even}\\ &\sum_{\lambda=0}^{(r-1)/2}\psi(t, 2\lambda+1, r),& t\text{ odd}.}\right.$$

(It doesn't matter that the upper limits $r/2$ and $(r-1)/2$ may be non-integral: by definition, the inner sum extends through all *integral* values of $\lambda$ that are less than or equal to the upper limit.  Most looping constructs in computing languages follow this convention.)

You can also change variables to, say, $t$ and $s=(t+l)/2,$ in which case $l=2s-t$ runs from $0$ to $r,$ whence $s$ ranges among all the integers within the interval from $t/2$ to $(t+r)/2.$ The smallest of those integers is the ceiling of $t/2,$ written $\lceil t/2 \rceil,$ and the largest is the floor of $(r+t)/2,$ written $\lfloor (r+t)/2 \rfloor,$ whence

$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty\ \sum_{\ell=0;\ t+l\text{ even}}^r \psi(t,\ell,r) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty \sum_{s=\lceil t/2 \rceil}^{\lfloor (r+t)/2 \rfloor} \psi(t, 2s-t, r).$$

Just make sure your program knows that when the upper limit of a sum is less than its lower limit, the sum is zero: this happens when $r=0$ and $t$ is odd.

---

There are other ways to re-express these sums, but most of them exploit the same tools: indicators, parity, conditionals, or the ceiling and floor functions.  Further analysis requires consideration of $\psi,$ the possibility of finding closed-form formulas for some of its partial sums, and numerical issues of floating point error accumulation.

Comment: thanks, I will take a look.